# Designing an ABBA circuit (3 input, 2 output) inputs: (GND, +V, Logic)

Tags: arduino, digital-logic, switches, kinect

I'm working on a relatively simple Arduino project and want to reach an elegant solution for a circuit. I'm not sure if there is an existing IC for what I want to do, but here is a diagram for what I'm attempting to accomplish.[image: ABBA Circuit Diagram]

When googling the solution I found the name to be an ABBA circuit (tagged by minecraft sadly), essentially I have 2 inputs which need to be switched when a 3rd logic trigger is activated. Can I do this with a single device? Or is there a more complex solution?

More stats:
+3V line has ~170 mA of current
Logic Switch is a +5V line with ~47 mA of current (Digital pin)

Thanks for taking a look and I appreciate any help given.

Comment: How much power does the output need?

Comment: Sorry, I added this to the original post now but the total output would be 3V*170mA ~= 0.5 Watts

Answer (score 1):

The device you're looking for is called an [**H Bridge**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H_bridge). They are frequently used to drive motors since they switch the power to either polarity which allows control of direction of rotation.

Since you need very low losses, you need to find one built using MOSFETs instead of BJTs.

[TI's Selection](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/amplifiers-linear/integrated-motor-driver-products.page#o7=Brushed%20DC%20Driver&p2122=1&p358min=1.8;5)

[Digi-Key, PMIC - MOSFET, Bridge Drivers - Internal Switch: H-Bridge](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?pv183=2231&FV=fff40027%2Cfff802d8&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25)

[Digi-Key, PMIC - Motor, Bridge Drivers: Brushed DC](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?pv1664=11&FV=fff40027%2Cfff802d2&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25)

Answer (score 1):

There's a very compact part (generically an H-bridge or motor driver) that provides this function, but soldering it might be your Waterloo: [LB1930MC](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/ENA2018-D.PDF) (pins are 1mm pitch). It will also perform the level shifting, but if you want to drive it with a single output you'd need to add an inverter or use two port pins. It was really björn to drive motors, but it will handle your 170mA with minimal voltage drop (less than 350mV).

[image]